# Como ejecutar condiciones al presionar boton

Tags: python, tkinter

Que tal, soy nuevo en programación en tkinter y estoy creando una interfaz gráfica para generar texto con interrupciones de un botón mi intención es que el código muestres el alfabeto y que se interrumpa el cursor en la fila deseada y comience a avanzar por columnas del alfabeto, y al volver a presionar el botón se seleccione ahora la letra deseada, esto con la intención de que se vayan generando palabras que se vayan mostrando en la misma interfaz, esto serviría para que personas que solo pueden mover un dedo puedan escribir, pero estoy atorado en el código en hacer que al presionar el boton cambie de filas a columnas, agradecería alguna orientación sobre como realizarlo ya que el código que tengo hasta ahora lo he ido realizando de varios post que he visto, muchas gracias.

```
bot = False

def LA():
    sv.set('''

>A        B       C        D        1        2

 E        F       G        H        3        4

 I        J       K        L        M        N

 O        P       Q        R        S        T

 U        V       W        X        Y        Z

5        6        7         8        9         0''')

def LB():
    sv.set('''

 A       >B       C        D        1        2

 E        F       G        H        3        4

 I        J       K        L        M        N

 O        P       Q        R        S        T

 U        V       W        X        Y        Z

5        6        7         8        9         0''')

def LC():
    sv.set('''

 A        B      >C        D        1        2

 E        F       G        H        3        4

 I        J       K        L        M        N

 O        P       Q        R        S        T

 U        V       W        X        Y        Z

5        6        7         8        9         0''')

def LD():
    sv.set('''

 A        B       C       >D        1        2

 E        F       G        H        3        4

 I        J       K        L        M        N

 O        P       Q        R        S        T

 U        V       W        X        Y        Z

5        6        7         8        9         0''')

def N1():
    sv.set('''

 A        B       C        D       >1        2

 E        F       G        H        3        4

 I        J       K        L        M        N

 O        P       Q        R        S        T

 U        V       W        X        Y        Z

5        6        7         8        9         0''')

def N2():
    sv.set('''

 A        B       C        D        1       >2

 E        F       G        H        3        4

 I        J       K        L        M        N

 O        P       Q        R        S        T

 U        V       W        X        Y        Z

5        6        7         8        9         0''')



def LE():

    sv.set('''

 A        B       C        D        1        2

>E        F       G        H        3        4

 I        J       K        L        M        N

 O        P       Q        R        S        T

 U        V       W        X        Y        Z

5        6        7         8        9         0''')

def LI():

    sv.set('''

 A        B       C        D        1        2

 E        F       G        H        3        4

>I        J       K        L        M        N

 O        P       Q        R        S        T

 U        V       W        X        Y        Z

5        6        7         8        9         0''')

def LO():

    sv.set('''

 A        B       C        D        1        2

 E        F       G        H        3        4

 I        J       K        L        M        N

>O        P       Q        R        S        T

 U        V       W        X        Y        Z

5        6        7         8        9         0''')

def LU():

    sv.set('''

 A        B       C        D        1        2

 E        F       G        H        3        4

 I        J       K        L        M        N

 O        P       Q        R        S        T

>U        V       W        X        Y        Z

5        6        7         8        9         0''')

def N5():

    sv.set('''

 A        B       C        D        1        2

 E        F       G        H        3        4

 I        J       K        L        M        N

 O        P       Q        R        S        T

 U        V       W        X        Y        Z

>5        6        7         8        9         0''')


def buttonClick():
    print("Boton Presionado")
    bot = True
    print(bot) 





from tkinter import *

t = 700

v0 = Tk()

v0.title("Sistema de comunicacion")

v0.geometry("800x480")

sv = StringVar()

et = Label (v0, textvariable = sv, font=("Helvetica", 17))

et.pack()

b = Button(v0, text="Presiona", command=buttonClick)

b.pack()

num = 0

i = 0

while True:



    et.after((num)*t,LA)
    i = i+1

    if (bot == True) :

        et.after((num+i)*t,LB)
        i = i+1

    else :

        et.after((num+i)*t,LE)
        i = i+1

        et.after((num+i)*t,LI)
        i = i+1

        et.after((num+3)*t,LO)
        i = i+1

        et.after((num+4)*t,LU)
        i = i+1

        et.after((num+5)*t,N5)
        i = i+1

    #print(bot)
    num = num + 6


    try:

        v0.update_idletasks()
        v0.update()
    except TclError:
        break
```

Comment: Bienvenido! A mi entender puede que tu código necesite muchas mejoras por lo que sea difícil de seguir siguiendo el formato de pregunta/respueta del sitio. [Aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) se explica como elaborar preguntas en el sitio. Puede que necesites descomponer tu pregunta en varias, con el objetivo de hacer ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Por otro lado,  ¿has visto ya o estás viendo algún tutorial de Python? Como por ejemplo [estos](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/index.html). También puedes ver si algún [tutorial de tkinter en  español](https://www.google.com.ar/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tutorial+tkinter+espa%C3%B1ol) que figuran buscando en Google es de tu agrado.

Answer (score 1):

Posiblemente, `tkinter` no sea el mejor entorno gráfico para desarrollar utilidades que requieran buen control de eventos. El método `after` que se usa para lanzar procesos temporales, no garantiza tiempos exactos, por lo que a veces se producen saltos que podrían despistar y agotar al usuario. Te aconsejo que pruebes con otros GUIs, como Qt o wx.

Centrándonos en tu código, he hecho algunas mejoras para que haga selecciones de letras, tal como pedías. Entre otras mejoras:

- La creación de la rejilla se hace de forma programática. Así es más simple adaptarla según se necesite y más simple localizar el elemento seleccionado.
- El widget de la rejilla se implementa como una clase derivada de `Frame`, lo que mejora su reutilización.
- La animación (`self.animate`) utiliza el método `after` del `root`, que requiere reactivarse una vez que termina la actualización de la rejilla
- Cuando se pulsa el botón, se debe parar la animación mientras se esté calculando la actualización. Se usa para ello `after_cancel`, y como parámetro el `id` del *proceso en espera* que se ha almacena en la variable `self._job`.

He intentado que sea lo más parecido al código de la pregunta. Espero que se entienda:
..

```
import tkinter as tk

GRID = [
    "ABCD12",
    "EFGH34",
    "IJKLMN",
    "OPQRST",
    "UVWXYZ",
    "567890",
]

class Rejilla(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, t=700):
        super().__init__(root)

        self.root = root
        self.t = t

        self.vertical = True
        self.row = 0
        self.col = 0
        self.nrows = len(GRID)
        self.ncols = len(GRID[0])

        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.res = tk.StringVar()

        self.g = tk.Label(root, textvariable = self.var, font=("Courier", 14))
        self.g.pack()

        result = tk.Label(root, textvariable = self.res, font=("Helvetica", 18), bg="yellow", width=30)
        result.pack()

        self.update()
        self.animate()

    def animate(self):
        if self.vertical:
            self.next_row()
        else:
            self.next_col()
        self.update()
        self._job = self.root.after(self.t, self.animate)

    def change_dir(self):
        self.root.after_cancel(self._job)

        if self.vertical:
            self.vertical = False
        else:
            self.vertical = True
            (i,j) = (self.row, self.col)
            (self.row, self.col) = (0,0)

            self.res.set(self.res.get() + GRID[i][j])

        self.update()
        self._job = self.root.after(self.t, self.animate)

    def next_row(self):
        self.row = (self.row+1)%self.nrows
        self.update()

    def next_col(self):
        self.col = (self.col+1)%self.ncols
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        pos = (self.row, self.col)
        self.var.set("\n\n".join(
            "        ".join(
                (">" if (r,c)==pos else " ") + col
                for (c,col) in enumerate(row))
            for (r,row) in enumerate(GRID)   
        ))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    v0 = tk.Tk()
    v0.title("Sistema de comunicacion")
    v0.geometry("800x480")

    r = Rejilla(v0)
    r.pack()

    b = tk.Button(v0, text="Presiona", command=r.change_dir)
    b.pack()

    v0.mainloop()
```